# Fill edge loop with evenly spaced grid

Tags: modeling, mesh

I created a shape, starting from a circle mesh, now I'm left with the following[image: heart shaped outline]

Now what I'd like to do is fill the inside with a mesh, but the grid needs to be somewhat even, that's because I would like to end up with something like my other model:

[image: button model]

I'm not too fussed about the topology connecting directly with the heart shape, but I would like the middle (of about the same size as the button's) to be an even grid, so I can poke the holes.
If it matters, the heart shape also can't be affected later on, since I plan to extrude it.

Is there a way to do this, or should I be doing it completely different?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a 24 vertex circle:

[image]

Bridge 17 of its vertices to the heart shape:

[image]

Extrude the vertices on the right:

[image]

Fill the holes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would using the grid fill tool give you the results you need?  You can find it under Faces > Grid Fill in Edit mode.

[Grid fill tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/grid_fill.html)